# how can i do a second validation with coodeigniter on data that has been post by angularJs before saving to the database

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, validation

I am working on a registration system and i am using angularJs as the front end and codeigniter as the backend. I am trying to do a two way validation **(client and Server)** but have some problems validating the data sent by angularJs to my codeigniter controller. Angular successfully post the data to the database after validation but when i try doing a second validation, the data sent to the database are **Null**. Now my question is, how can i do a second validation on the server so that the application can have both validations for security reasons.

**ANGULAR JS HANDLES INPUT HERE**

```
     $scope.registration = {
        fullName: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        country: '',
        gender: '',
        town: '',
        refEmail: ''
     }
     $scope.registerSuccess = "";
     $scope.registerFailed = "";

     //Function below submits registration form to the server after validations

     $scope.submitRegisterForm = function(){
        $scope.dataloading = '';
        console.log($scope.registration);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php/register/registerUser',
            data: $scope.registration,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},

        }).then(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $scope.registerSuccess = data;
                $scope.message = data;
                $scope.registration = {};
            })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.registerFailed = data;
        })
    }
```

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
    $request= json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
    $fullName = $request->fullName;
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;
    $refEmail = $request->refEmail;
    $gender = $request->gender;
    $country = $request->country;
    $town = $request->town;
    echo $fullName;

    $checkName = $this->form_validation->set_rules($fullName, 'Full Name', 'trim|required|min_lenght[5]|is_unique[users.full_name]');
    $checkName = $this->form_validation->set_rules($email, 'Email Address', 'trim|required|min_lenght[5]|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
    $checkName = $this->form_validation->set_rules($password, 'User Password', 'trim|required|min_lenght[5]');
    $checkName = $this->form_validation->set_rules($refEmail, 'Referrer Email ID', 'trim|required');
    $checkName = $this->form_validation->set_rules($gender, 'Gender', 'trim|required');
    $checkName = $this->form_validation->set_rules($country, 'Country', 'trim|required');
    $checkName = $this->form_validation->set_rules($town, 'Town', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $validate = array('error' => validation_errors());
        $this->session->set_flashdata($validate);
        echo json_encode($validate);
    }else{
    $this->load->model('user');
    $result = $this->user->saveUser($request);

    if ($result) {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message'=> 'Registration successfull'));
        // $this->load->view('users_view/email_confirmation_view_message', array('email'=>$result));
    }else{
        // this should never happen
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>false, 'message'=> 'Registration Failed'));
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

not so much an answer - but words of advice to start.  Cannot make comments yet :)

I found using codeigniter in an API fashion a little tough.  I wrote my own validation when trying to do this.

You don't need to assign

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules()
```

to a variable.

You are echo'ing back

```
echo $fullName;
```

at the start, so your ajax call would receive this as its data back.

You should not need the flashdata as you can handle this on the front end from the data you get back from your Ajax call.

Sidenote: If you have further conditions after an expecting return 'echo' then exit() to stop the flow of the function.  Good to write a helper function for this IE called with:

```
returnJson($response)
```

which exits for you after echo and json_encodes the data.

Could we see your model for database entry.  The issue could well be there.

Comment: just re--read and saw you are passing `true` as the second param to json_decode().  I don't understand how this would work without throwing a warning message.  passing `true` will turn the result `$request` to an associative array, not an object.  Therefore you could not call `$fullName = $request->fullName;
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;
    $refEmail = $request->refEmail;
    $gender = $request->gender;
    $country = $request->country;
    $town = $request->town;` as the properties do not exist.  It would be `$request['email']` etc instead.

Comment: Yeah i also tried to user $request['email'] to get the json decoded data so that i can proceed with the server validation but everything goes to the server as null

Comment: when i don't apply any server validations, the data is saved correctly in the database.

Comment: So to confirm, when you just do this: `$request= json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE); $this->load->model('user');
    $result = $this->user->saveUser($request);` it works?

Comment: Also, did you load the Codeigniter validation library `$this->load->library('form_validation');` ?

Comment: Yeah when i do this
    '$request= json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE); $this->load->model('user'); $result = $this->user->saveUser($request);'  it works and i have loaded the validation library